# Applying a style to an element in CSS depending on the following elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

**Short Version:** Is there a way to apply a style to an HTML element in CSS only if it is followed by another specific element?

**Longer version:**
The situation is as follows:
I am creating content using a help authoring tool (MadCap Flare). Let's say I have the following code:

```
<ol>
 <li>First li</li>
 <li>Second li</li>
</ol>
<p>A (conditional) paragraph.</p>
<ol>
 <li>Third li</li>
 <li>Fourth li</li>
</ol>
```

Let's also say the ol has a margin-bottom of 8px, while a li has a margin-bottom of 2px.

The paragraph in the middle might or might not show up in my output, depending on some condition. If the paragraph is there, the margin of the ol will apply. No problem there.

If the paragraph is not there, however, I would like the ol element to have a smaller margin - just the 2px the li-Elements have. In this case, I want it to look like there is just one list.

My dream solution would be to give the ol a margin of 2px if and only if it is followed by another ol. Is there a way to do this with CSS, or will I have to tweak this in some other way?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. See the suggested duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that thread. Seems like I didn't really know what to look for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not thinking differently about this and move the margin to the `p` element instead. So the `ol` will have a `margin-bottom` of `2px` (the last `li`) and in case there is a `p` element you will add `6px` margin to `p` to have the `8px` margin:

```css
ol {
  margin:0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
ol + p {
  margin-top:6px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>First li</li>
 <li>Second li</li>
</ol>
<p>A (conditional) paragraph.</p>
<ol>
 <li>Third li</li>
 <li>Fourth li</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li>First li</li>
 <li>Second li</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li>Third li</li>
 <li>Fourth li</li>
</ol>
```

In case it can be any element other than `p` you can try this:

```css
ol {
  margin:0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
ol + *:not(ol) {
  margin-top:6px;
  margin-bottom:8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
 <li>First li</li>
 <li>Second li</li>
</ol>
<section>A (conditional) paragraph.</section>
<ol>
 <li>Third li</li>
 <li>Fourth li</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li>First li</li>
 <li>Second li</li>
</ol>
<ol>
 <li>Third li</li>
 <li>Fourth li</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for making me look at this from another angle. Your first suggestion does work! Now I just have to check if there are any strangely formatted p classes or cases, where other elements stand between those ols. MadCap Flare for some reason does not seem to understand the :not pseudo class (or I'm doing something wrong here), so your second suggestion is not an option.